# How to enable href anchor inside Rich Text Box [AEM 6.1 TOUCH UI DIALOG]

Tags: html, hyperlink, dialog, anchor, aem

I am using Adobe Experience Manager v6.1 (TOUCH UI) and I desire to make it possible to insert an hyperlink

```
<a href=""></a>
```

among the words written inside the content of a rich text box field of a component dialog. How can I do this?

EXAMPLE: I write something inside the rich text box field, for example "lorem ipsum bla vla" and I'd like to obtain in page a code like the following

```
lorem <a href="www://ejnejcejcn">ipsum</a> bla vla
```

thanks
Alessandro

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring the Rich Text Editor you just need to select the words you want to be the link, then click the link button and fill the data.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Estebusta, I've tried the solution you have proposed to me but it doesn't work. It seems that the Touch UI loses the href value because of a bug...THANKS ANYWAY